# CSRF Invalid because of two entities in the registration process

Tags: php, symfony, csrf

I have **two entities** and one form for the registration process.When I add csrf token it probably works for **one of them**, not for both.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="registerForm" id="registerForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" name="company[name]" id="companyName" placeholder="Име на фирма" required/>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" name="company[bulstat]" id="bulstat" placeholder="Булстат" required/>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" name="user[username]" id="username" placeholder="Потребителско име" required/>
        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" name="user[email]" id="email" placeholder="Имейл адрес" required/>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" name="user[password]" id="password" placeholder="Парола" required/>
        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
    </div>
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" id="registerButton">Create account</button></div>
</form>
```

**The output is**: "user__token" so as far as I can see it generates it with the exception that is affects only **one of the two entities** - User and it does **not** work for the other one.

**When I remove** the company fields everything works like a charm.

The forms are:

1.User

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $schools = $this->schoolRepository->findAll();

    $builder
        ->add('username', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'csrf_protection' => true,
        'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        'csrf_token_id'   => 'task_item'
    ));
}
```

2.Company:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
    $builder->add('bulstat', TextType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company',
        'csrf_protection' => true,
        'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        'csrf_token_id'   => 'task_item'
    ));
}
```

The controller where forms are being created:

```
$company = new Company();
$companyForm = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $company);
$companyForm->handleRequest($request);

$user = new User();
$userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
$userForm->handleRequest($request);
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Hi, could you add the code of your controller also. Here you have two forms and you have to handle each form separately

Comment: Yeah, I will. The code is too long but I'll add the piece where it's being handled.

Comment: I've been thinking, CSRF works for one form, right? What if I managed somehow to combine those two into one? Just an idea. I don't know how to do it or even whether it would work or not.

Comment: Yes, one form can contain two entities.  I take it (from the posted code) that you are not using the Symfony framework?

Comment: I do use it. Why would you thought of such an idea? It is definitely Symfony. I would love if you, sir, could offer me any appropriate way to overcome that obstacle.

Comment: $userForm->handleRequest($request); makes little sense in a Symfony controller.  Plus, the way you spell out your html instead of using the twig form functions means you are working much harder than you have to.  In any event, add $company and $user to an array and make a third form type (call it RegisterType) which includes both the CompanyType as well as UserType.  Then just use {{ form(form) }} for testing.  Once it is working, go back and add your styling.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using version 3.4.If I'm correct, it turns out that method does not work correctly probably I am doing something wrong.The error message I get is: "Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\CompanyType" given".The very first "add" parameter is string and the second is the corresponding FormType.

Comment: You are passing an instance of CompanyType instead of the class name.  Should have something like ->add('company', CompanyType::class).  See the answer below for what should be a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a question of how to combine two entities into one form.  There are other questions that address this but some are a bit old and out of date.  This question is also an example of not taking advantage of what Symfony has to offer and working a bit harder than the developer has to.

Specifically, Symfony deals with csrf out of the box and requires no special configuration.  You can do more stuff with it but it is easier to start with a default working implementation and then tweak if necessary.  In a similar fashion, twig has a default rendering of a form.  After the form is working you can then use various styling tools to make it look pretty.

Start by simplifying your EntityType classes and adding a RegisterType:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ));
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class);
    }
}
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Company::class,
        ));
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('bulstat', TextType::class);
    }
}
class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', UserType::class)
            ->add('company', CompanyType::class)
            ->add('register', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

Now adjust the controller code and use the default form rendering:

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $company = new Company();
        $register = ['user' => $user, 'company' => $company];

        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, $register);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($user);
            dump($company);
        }

        return $this->render('register.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
# register.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

At this point you should have a working form.  You can then add validation and persistence as well as making the form look nice.

Comment: The method "IsValid" returns false which means that there is some error.Since we've wrapped the three forms into one how could I access each form messages individually? If I'm correct I do get two errors which are about invalid CSRF and that there are some extra fields.

Comment: Out of the box, the code I posted will render any errors.  Check the docs for more details.